# How to implement POM for "driver.FindElements"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I was using POM for initializing my elements as below.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//ion-buttons[2]/button")]
    public IWebElement SearchIcon { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.searchbar-input")]
    public IWebElement SearchTextbox { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "item-wrapper")]
    public IWebElement fixedcontent { get; set; }
```

But how to use below line of code on above format:

```
IList<IWebElement> propertyList1 = Setup.driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("name"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# you use the following:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "name')]
private IList<IWebElement> propertyList1 { get; set; }
```

Btw, notice I've declared the locator as "private". As a general rule you don't make locators in a POM "public".

Comment: +1 but why add { get; set; }?

Comment: That's C# shorthand for "use the usual accessor methods". There's a good explanation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001941/3456626)

Comment: Why would you write them for a private variable? Is there any added value versus `private IWebElement element;`?

Comment: Your locators should only really be accessed by the page object they belong to. So be default you should always mark them as private unless you have a really good reason not to. Using the propertyList1 example above, lets say you want to get one of the properties in the list. In your page object you would declare a public method that accesses that locator list and then used that method in your test code. You would never access propertyList1 directly in your test. So by declaring it as private you ensure that no one can accidentally do that.

Comment: Oh, I see. In all my tests I have never needed a WebElement outside of its Page Object, that's why I didn't see the use for it.

Comment: I just realised I misunderstood your question. The solution I gave declares "propertyList1" as a Property were as the example you gave declares "element" as a Field. Other than it being good OOP practice to use encapsulation, I'm not sure there is a huge difference between the two in this case. It's a pretty big topic though. You might want to check out [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) for a more extensive discussion of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing my answer in java:

```
@FindBys(
@FindBy(classname=”name”))
public List<WebElement> propertyList1;
```

or

```
@FindBys(
@FindBy(how = How.CLASSNAME, Using=”name”))
public List<WebElement> propertyList1;
```

**Additional Information:**
We can use `@FindAll` with multiple `@FindBy` annotations to look for elements that match any of the given locators:

```
@FindAll({
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using=”username”),
    @FindBy(className=”username-field”)
  })
private WebElement user_name;
```

I would also recommend to [read](https://www.toptal.com/selenium/test-automation-in-selenium-using-page-object-model-and-page-factory) for future reference.

Comment: Thanks, But im up to C# dude